# Trouble with the Jacobian for a camera projection matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, partial-derivative, jacobian, total-variation

I am using the Gauss Newton method to update a camera projection matrix.
$$
x = \frac{PX}{P_\text{last row} X}
$$
where x is a known $3\times k$ matrix, X is a known $4\times k$ matrix, and
$$
P = 
\begin{bmatrix}
p_1 & p_2 & p_3 & p_4\\
p_5 & p_6 & p_7 & p_8\\
p_{9} & p_{10} & p_{11} & p_{12}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I have a loss function I want to minimize L, where
$$
R(P) = \frac{PX}{P_\text{last row} X} - x
$$
and unroll r into
$$
r(P) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
R(P)_{1,1} \\ R(P)_{2,1} \\ \vdots \\ R(P)_{2,k} \\ R(P)_{3,k}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
then
$$
L(P) = r(P)^T \cdot r(P)
$$
I unroll P into a vector p
$$
p = 
\begin{bmatrix}
p_1 \\ p_2 \\ \vdots \\ p_{11} \\ p_{12}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I know
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial P} =  2 \frac{\partial r}{\partial 
P} r(P)
$$
and then I have my Jacobian where I want to find
$$
\frac{\partial r(P)}{\partial p} = J =
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial r(P)_{1,1}}{\partial p_1} & \cdots & \frac{\partial r(P)_{1,1}}{\partial p_{12}}\\
\frac{\partial r(P)_{2,1}}{\partial p_1} & \cdots & \frac{\partial r(P)_{2,1}}{\partial p_{12}}\\
\frac{\partial r(P)_{1,2}}{\partial p_1} & \cdots & \frac{\partial r(P)_{1,2}}{\partial p_{12}}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\frac{\partial r(P)_{2,k}}{\partial p_1} & \cdots & \frac{\partial r(P)_{2,k}}{\partial p_{12}}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I removed the rows that don't depend on P, every third row, because the last row of the output is always 1.

$$
\frac{\partial R(P)_{1,i}}{\partial P_{1, j}} = \frac{X_{j, i}}{X_{1, i}P_{3, 1} + X_{2, i}P_{3, 2} + X_{3, i}P_{3, 3} + X_{4, i}P_{3, 4}} = \frac{X_{j,i}}{c_i}\\
\frac{\partial R(P)_{1,i}}{\partial P_{2, j}} = 0 \\
\frac{\partial R(P)_{1,i}}{\partial P_{3, j}} = \frac{X_{j, i}(X_{1, i}P_{1, 1} + X_{2, i}P_{1, 2} + X_{3, i}P_{1, 3} + X_{4, i}P_{1, 4})}{(X_{1, i}P_{3, 1} + X_{2, i}P_{3, 2} + X_{3, i}P_{3, 3} + X_{4, i}P_{3, 4})^2} = \frac{X_{j, i}a_i}{c_i^2}\\
\frac{\partial R(P)_{2,i}}{\partial P_{1, j}} = 0 \\
\frac{\partial R(P)_{2,i}}{\partial P_{2, j}} = \frac{X_{j, i}}{X_{1, i}P_{3, 1} + X_{2, i}P_{3, 2} + X_{3, i}P_{3, 3} + X_{4, i}P_{3, 4}} = \frac{X_{j,i}}{c_i}\\
\frac{\partial R(P)_{2,i}}{\partial P_{3, j}} = \frac{X_{j, i}(X_{1, i}P_{2, 1} + X_{2, i}P_{2, 2} + X_{3, i}P_{2, 3} + X_{4, i}P_{2, 4})}{(X_{1, i}P_{3, 1} + X_{2, i}P_{3, 2} + X_{3, i}P_{3, 3} + X_{4, i}P_{3, 4})^2} = \frac{X_{j, i}b_i}{c_i^2} \\
\vdots
$$
Doing some substitution I get
$$
J =
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{X_{1,1}}{c_1} & 0 & \frac{X_{1, 1}a_1}{c_1^2} & \cdots & \frac{X_{4, 1}a_1}{c_1^2}\\
0 & \frac{X_{1,1}}{c_1} & \frac{X_{1, 1}b_1}{c_1^2} & \cdots & \frac{X_{4, 1}b_1}{c_1^2}\\
\frac{X_{1,2}}{c_2} & 0 & \frac{X_{1, 2}a_2}{c_2^2} & \cdots & \frac{X_{4, 2}a_2}{c_2^2}\\
0 & \frac{X_{1,2}}{c_2} & \frac{X_{1, 2}b_2}{c_2^2} & \cdots & \frac{X_{4, 2}b_2}{c_2^2}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & \frac{X_{1,k}}{c_2} & \cdots & \cdots & \frac{X_{4, k}b_k}{c_k^2}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

But when plugging this into the Gauss-Newton Method:

$$
p_{n+1} = p_n - (J^TJ)^{-1}J^Tr(P_n)
$$

It just gives me wildly incorrect results. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: According to the [convergence section of the gauss-newton wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Newton_algorithm#Convergence_properties) "convergence is not guaranteed, not even local convergence as in Newton's method". I think my Jacobian is correct, its just possible that It will never converge. Take my opinion with a grain of salt though, I'm the one who asked the question haha.

Comment: Of course I would love a way to solve this directly from the projection matrix, but If you are looking to solve the same problem I am, Telesens seems to have a [reasonable solution](https://www.telesens.co/2016/10/13/bundle-adjustment-part-1-jacobians/) that goes a different route.

Comment: I wrote some related notes and code here: https://github.com/danielvoconnor/MultipleViewGeometry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For convenience,
the cost function is rewritten as
$ 
\phi 
= 
\| \mathbf{R} \|_F^2
$
with the $3 \times k$ residual  matrix
$$
\mathbf{R} = 
\mathbf{U}-\mathbf{X}_\mathrm{meas}
$$
and
$$
\mathbf{U}
=
\mathbf{V} 
\mathbf{D}^{-1}
$$
where
$$
\mathbf{V} 
=
\mathbf{P}\mathbf{X},
\mathbf{D}
=
\mathrm{diag}(\mathbf{V}^T \mathbf{e}_3)
$$

\noindent
We deduce
\begin{eqnarray*}
d\mathbf{R}=
d\mathbf{U}
&=&
(d\mathbf{V}) \mathbf{D}^{-1}
-
\mathbf{U}
(d\mathbf{D})
\mathbf{D}^{-1} \\
&=&
\mathbf{I}_3 (d\mathbf{P}) \mathbf{X} \mathbf{D}^{-1}
-
\mathbf{U}
(d\mathbf{D})
\mathbf{D}^{-1} 
\end{eqnarray*}
Vectorization yields
\begin{eqnarray*}
d\mathbf{r}
&=&
\left[
(
\mathbf{X} 
\mathbf{D}^{-1}
)^T
\otimes
\mathbf{I}_3
\right] 
d\mathbf{p}
-
(\mathbf{D}^{-1} \ast \mathbf{U})
(d\mathbf{V})^T \mathbf{e}_3 \\
&=&
\left[
\mathbf{D}^{-1}
\mathbf{X}^T
\otimes
\mathbf{I}_3
\right] 
d\mathbf{p}-
(\mathbf{D}^{-1} \ast \mathbf{U})
\mathbf{X}^T
\mathbf{I}_4
(d\mathbf{P})^T \mathbf{e}_3 \\
&=&
\left[
\mathbf{D}^{-1}
\mathbf{X}^T
\otimes
\mathbf{I}_3
\right] 
d\mathbf{p}-
(\mathbf{D}^{-1} \ast \mathbf{U})
\mathbf{X}^T
(\mathbf{e}_3^T \otimes \mathbf{I}_4)
d\mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{P}^T)
\end{eqnarray*}
where we have used the Khatri-Rao product $\ast$.

Using the vec-permutation matrix $\mathbf{K}$,
the $3k \times 12$
Jacobian writes in matrix form as
$$
\left[
\mathbf{D}^{-1}
\mathbf{X}^T
\otimes
\mathbf{I}_3
\right] 
-
(\mathbf{D}^{-1} \ast \mathbf{U})
\mathbf{X}^T
(\mathbf{e}_3^T \otimes \mathbf{I}_4)
\mathbf{K}
$$

The second term of the Jacobian has an effect only on columns 3-6-9-12.

Comment: When I include both the first term and the second term of the jacobian it diverges to infinity. However, when I remove the second term, the solution converges to an incorrect answer. Since everything else in the second term seems to make sense, it makes me think I don't quite understand what the K matrix is doing. Does the K matrix just permute the columns of the second term so columns 9,10,11,12 are permuted to 3,6,9,12?

Comment: It also converges to something (incorrect) when I change the minus to a plus sign for the second term in the jacobian. I think this may just be a coincidence.

Comment: I think the issue might be that the $D^{-1} \ast U$ should be swapped so its $U \ast D^{-1}$ both give correct dimensions, but this way converges and it does so in a way that seems more correct.

Comment: Turns out my last 2 comments are completely wrong. The order of $D^{-1} \ast U$ is correct in the above solution, and converging when changing the minus to a plus was a coincidence. I tested this against a numerical solution and It was within a small epsilon of the above solution.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbf{K}$ is a so-called commutation matrix [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20especially%20in%20linear,vectorized%20form%20of%20its%20transpose.&text=Replacing%20A%20with%20AT,K%20%3D%20(K)T.).
It is populated of $0$s and $1$s (only one non-zero entry per row)
The second term of the Jacobian is a 3k-by-12 matrix where
the column 3 is the first column of $(\mathbf{D}^{-1} \ast \mathbf{U})
\mathbf{X}^T$,
the column 6 is the second column of $(\mathbf{D}^{-1} \ast \mathbf{U})
\mathbf{X}^T$ and so on

Comment: Ah, I think I understand. So, Since $(D^{-1} \ast U)X^T$is a $3k \times 4$ matrix,  and $e_3^T \bigotimes I_4$ is a $ 4 \times 12$ matrix, $K$ must be a $ 12 \times 12$ permutation matrix that has $e_9$ in the 3rd column, $e_{10}$ in the 6th column, $e_{11}$ in the 9th column, $e_{12}$ in the 12 column, and zeros everywhere else. When we multiply $Z = (e_3^T \bigotimes I_4)K$ we get a $4 \times 12$ matrix again, where the columns of $Z$ are $e_1$ in the 3rd column, $e_2$ in the 6th column, $e_3$ in the 9th column, $e_4$ in the 12th column, and zero everywhere else.